# VHDL 8 bits full adder using eigth 1 bit full adder

Tags: vhdl

Good evening, I'm trying to implement a 8 bits full adder in vhdl, but for that I need to use eight complete 1-bit full adders. I know how to do the 8bits full adder, but I don't know how to use the eight 1bit full adder.
I have this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity onebitfulladder is

port (num1, num2, carry_in : in std_logic;
result, carry_out : out std_logic);

end onebitfulladder;

architecture behavior of onebitfulladder is

signal S1, S2, S3 : std_logic;

begin
result <= num1 xor num2 xor carry_in;
S1 <= num1 and num2;
S2 <= num1 and carry_in;
S3 <= carry_in and num2;
carry_out <= S1 or S2 or S3;
end behavior;
```

Basically, I need to use 1-bit adders to implement a full 8-bit adder. I've implemented the full 1 bit adder, but I do not know how to use it to form an 8 bit adder.

Comment: See [8 bit adder codes in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148122/8-bit-adder-codes-in-vhdl). Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes, i have. I can't use the STD_LOGIC_VECTOR, and this is my problem, i don't know how to use the code that i mentioned above to do this.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Basically, I need to use 1-bit adders to implement a full 8-bit adder. I've implemented the full 1 bit adder, but I do not know how to use it to form an 8 bit adder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call the code you gave "onebitfulladder". You should have a VHDL file onebitfulladder.vhd

You will want to create a new file "eightbitadder" where you declare and instantiate the component "onebitfulladder".

There are lots of tutorials explaining how to create components in VHDL:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/compinst.html

Then you can create the eightbitadder by instantiating 8 onebitfulladder